How to use Azure Service Bus endpoint with a CNAME Record
I have a publicly accessible Azure service bus.
And this has service bus is consumed by a PaaS application (SAP CRM).
Since it is publicly available, I need to restrict the access.
So what I did was;

Disable the public access and allow only shared network and whitelist the IP

But Since we don't know the IP of this PaaS or it can change overtime, this is not a reliable solution. We thought of going with a private endpoint.
Eveything works fine until the private endpoint is created. As the private endpoint is reoslved with a private DNS (mysb.privatelink.servicebus.windows.net), the PaaS application now cannot be able to access that as wherever this PaaS doesn't know about this private DNS entry - mysb.privatelink.servicebus.windows.net
Is there a way I can have a CNAME record in my public DNS zone and resolve/direct the traffic to the Private DNS zone record (mysb.privatelink.servicebus.windows.net) created above?
I will be grateful if you can give me some insights on how to do this.
Thank You!

One possible scenario is connecting your Azure VNET that contains your Service bus and private link to your PAAS application via Point to Site VPN and then registering your Vnet to the Private DNS Zone like below:-
This way the PAAS application will be able to connect to your Service bus with DNS securely.
Private DNS zone:-

